# Mixing instance attributes and fields in Python data classes

Tags: python, instance-variables, python-dataclasses

I would like to "mix and match" instance attributes and dataclass fields, effectively extending dataclasses to optional attributes with computable values. I try to do this by using a default dataclass (so no explicit init method), but instantiating instance attributes (not Fields) in `__post_init__`. That does not seem to please my IDE, though, as it warns me that these attributes were "defined outside an init method".

import dataclasses
from typing import Optional, List

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Word:
    text: str

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.chars: List[str] = self.text.split()
        self.alt_text: Optional[str] = None
        self.alt_text_chars: Optional[List[str]] = None

    def add_alt_text(self, text: str):
        self.alt_text = text  # IDE complains that instance attribute is defined outside init
        self.alt_text_chars = text.split()  # IDE complains


word = Word("hello")
word.add_alt_text("good morning")
```

Does that mean that what I want to achieve is not possible, i.e. mixing instance attributes alongside regular dataclass fields? Or is there a (PEP-y) way around that is allowed?

As a side note: sometimes you explicitly want attributes to not be treated the same as fields. For instance, when your dataclass has `__eq__` (the default), then you may want to compare ONLY the fields but not *all* of its attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage fields by listing them in the dataclass using `field()` and passing `init=False` and `compare=False` to the `field` call, although I am not sure this is what you are looking for.